# multiline label for node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Is there way of producing multiline label for node:

```
\node[label=below:{unit\\cell}]  (one){\tikz{\draw (0,0)rectangle (1,1);}};
```

The example produces "wrong" label output: *untitcell*

However, following code:

```
\node (one){\tikz{\draw (0,0)rectangle (1,1);}};
\path (one) node [below,align=center] {unit\\cell};
```

produces correct doble-line label, but alas wrong positioning...

Comment: `[text width=1cm]` but  the question is not precise. You want multilines but where ... why `\tikz{\draw (0,0)rectangle (1,1);}`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't nest TikZ pictures (unless you really have to), it has some nontrivial consequences. Labels are also nodes(almost) only placed differently. If you add `draw` option to your node, you don't need to draw it's box additionally.

You can also pass regular options to the label node (because it's a node) as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum size=1cm,label={[align=center]below:unit\\cell}] (one){};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

If it becomes tedious to write complicated label codes just use the positioning syntax

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum size=1cm] (one){};
\node[align=center,anchor=north] (lab) at (one.south) {unit\\cell};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which leads to the same result. There are a few more ways of doing it but no need to complicate it for this simple application. You can find many examples here too by searching for positioning library use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Well, I really have to, because instead of rectangle there is a more or less complex structure drawn.

Comment: @percusse When I execute your code, I obtain the square but with 'unitcell' on one line. MWE: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning} \tikzset{block/.style={draw,fill=blue!20,rectangle,minimum height=2em,minimum width=4em},sum/.style={draw,fill=blue!20,circle,node distance=1cm},input/.style={coordinate},output/.style={coordinate},pinstyle/.sty‌​le={pin edge={to-,thin,black}}} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \node[draw,minimum size=1cm](one){}; \node[align=center,anchor=north](lab) at (one.south) {unit\\cell}; \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}`

Comment: @MWijnand I get the linebroken version. Are you sure you have `align=center`?

Comment: @percusse Apparently, following error message shows up:
_Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/align' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it._

Comment: Good thing : it works the same with `pin` instead of label
Strange thing : you **must** specify `align`=_something_ or the line break is ignored.